# Java concurrency counter not properly clean up

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

This is a java concurrency question. 10 jobs need to be done, each of them will have 32 worker threads. Worker thread will increase a counter . Once the counter is 32, it means this job is done and then clean up counter map. From the console output, I expect that 10 "done" will be output, pool size is 0 and counterThread size is 0.

The issues are :

1. most of time, "pool size: 0 and countThreadMap size:3" will be
   printed out. even those all threads are gone, but 3 jobs are not
   finished yet.
2. some time, I can see nullpointerexception in line 27. I have used ConcurrentHashMap and AtomicLong, why still have concurrency
   exception.

Thanks

```
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

public class Test {
    final ConcurrentHashMap<Long, AtomicLong[]> countThreadMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<Long, AtomicLong[]>();
    final ExecutorService cachedThreadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    final ThreadPoolExecutor tPoolExecutor = ((ThreadPoolExecutor) cachedThreadPool);

    public void doJob(final Long batchIterationTime) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
            Thread workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (countThreadMap.get(batchIterationTime) == null) {
                        AtomicLong[] atomicThreadCountArr = new AtomicLong[2];
                        atomicThreadCountArr[0] = new AtomicLong(1);
                        atomicThreadCountArr[1] = new AtomicLong(System.currentTimeMillis()); //start up time
                        countThreadMap.put(batchIterationTime, atomicThreadCountArr);
                    } else {
                        AtomicLong[] atomicThreadCountArr = countThreadMap.get(batchIterationTime);
                        atomicThreadCountArr[0].getAndAdd(1);
                        countThreadMap.put(batchIterationTime, atomicThreadCountArr);
                    }

                    if (countThreadMap.get(batchIterationTime)[0].get() == 32) {
                        System.out.println("done");
                        countThreadMap.remove(batchIterationTime);
                    }
                }
            });
            tPoolExecutor.execute(workerThread);
        }
    }

    public void report(){
        while(tPoolExecutor.getActiveCount() != 0){
            //
        }
        System.out.println("pool size: "+ tPoolExecutor.getActiveCount() + " and countThreadMap size:"+countThreadMap.size());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Test test = new Test();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Long batchIterationTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            test.doJob(batchIterationTime);
        }

        test.report();
        System.out.println("All Jobs are done");

    }
}
```

Comment: You know the report() method isn't atomic, right? There's a race between the different size checks.

Comment: do you mean this line is not thread safety ? tPoolExecutor.getActiveCount()

Comment: The while loop in `report()`... Is that really a tight loop or is there actual code there where the `//` is? If it's a tight loop - That's not how you wait for threads to finish.

Comment: @EdwardChen: I mean you fetched those two stats at different instants, so there's no reason to assume they're consistent or the operation was atomic.

Comment: This code makes my head hurt. Why are you converting an `ExecutorService` to a `ThreadPoolExecutor`? Just to be able to call `getActiveCount()`?

Comment: Also, just because you are using a `ConcurrentHashMap` does not mean you are using it in a thread-safe way. You are not synchronizing access properly (look up check-then-act). This is also a fairly abstract question, and probably an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: ConcurrentHashMap#put and get are both thread safety. correct ? even I add a ReentrantLock into run method, still get NullPointerException

Comment: @EdwardChen `put` and `get` are thread-safe, but calling `get` and then later calling `put` expecting the map's state to have stayed the same in the interim is wrong. just look up check-then-act, this code is badly broken. it would be helpful if you would describe (using words, not code) what your goal is. let's assume your code above was perfect and working, what would you be doing with it? in my opinion, **that** is the important question.

Comment: @Sean, we need to know all of worker threads for one job are all finished.

Answer (score 1):

Let’s dig through all the mistakes of thread related programming, one man can make:

```
Thread workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
…
tPoolExecutor.execute(workerThread);
```

You create a `Thread` but don’t start it but submit it to an executor. It’s a historical mistake of the Java API to let `Thread` implement `Runnable` for no good reason. Now, every developer should be aware, that there is no reason to treat a `Thread` as a `Runnable`. If you don’t want to [`start`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start--) a thread manually, don’t create a `Thread`. Just create the `Runnable` and pass it to `execute` or [`submit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit-java.lang.Runnable-).

I want to emphasize the latter as it returns a `Future` which gives you for free what you are attempting to implement: the information when a task has been finished. It’s even easier when using [`invokeAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll-java.util.Collection-) which will submit a bunch of `Callable`s and return when all are done. Since you didn’t tell us anything about your actual task, it’s not clear whether you can let your tasks simply implement `Callable` (may return `null`) instead of `Runnable`.

If you can’t use `Callable`s or don’t want to wait immediately on submission, you have to remember the returned `Future`s and query them at a later time:

```
static final ExecutorService cachedThreadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

public static List<Future<?>> doJob(final Long batchIterationTime) {
    final Random r=new Random();
    List<Future<?>> list=new ArrayList<>(32);
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        Runnable job=new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // pretend to do something
                LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(r.nextInt(10)));
            }
        };
        list.add(cachedThreadPool.submit(job));
    }
    return list;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Test test = new Test();
    Map<Long,List<Future<?>>> map=new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Long batchIterationTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while(map.containsKey(batchIterationTime))
            batchIterationTime++;
        map.put(batchIterationTime,doJob(batchIterationTime));
    }
    // print some statistics, if you really need
    int overAllDone=0, overallPending=0;
    for(Map.Entry<Long,List<Future<?>>> e: map.entrySet()) {
        int done=0, pending=0;
        for(Future<?> f: e.getValue()) {
            if(f.isDone()) done++;
            else  pending++;
        }
        System.out.println(e.getKey()+"\t"+done+" done, "+pending+" pending");
        overAllDone+=done;
        overallPending+=pending;
    }
    System.out.println("Total\t"+overAllDone+" done, "+overallPending+" pending");
    // wait for the completion of all jobs
    for(List<Future<?>> l: map.values())
        for(Future<?> f: l)
            f.get();
    System.out.println("All Jobs are done");
}
```

But note that if you don’t need the `ExecutorService` for subsequent tasks, it’s much easier to wait for all jobs to complete:

```
cachedThreadPool.shutdown();
cachedThreadPool.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS);
System.out.println("All Jobs are done");
```

---

But regardless of how unnecessary the manual tracking of the job status is, let’s delve into your attempt, so you may avoid the mistakes in the future:

```
if (countThreadMap.get(batchIterationTime) == null) {
```

The `ConcurrentMap` is thread safe, but this does not turn your concurrent code into sequential one (that would render multi-threading useless). The above line might be processed by up to all 32 threads at the same time, all finding that the key does not exist yet so possibly more than one thread will then be going to put the initial value into the map.

```
                    AtomicLong[] atomicThreadCountArr = new AtomicLong[2];
                    atomicThreadCountArr[0] = new AtomicLong(1);
                    atomicThreadCountArr[1] = new AtomicLong(System.currentTimeMillis());
                    countThreadMap.put(batchIterationTime, atomicThreadCountArr);
```

That’s why this is called the “check-then-act” anti-pattern. If more than one thread is going to process that code, they all will `put` their new value, being confident that this was the right thing as they have checked the initial condition before acting but for all but one thread the condition has changed when acting and they are overwriting the value of a previous `put` operation.

```
                } else {
                    AtomicLong[] atomicThreadCountArr = countThreadMap.get(batchIterationTime);
                    atomicThreadCountArr[0].getAndAdd(1);
                    countThreadMap.put(batchIterationTime, atomicThreadCountArr);
```

Since you are modifying the `AtomicInteger` which is already stored into the map, the `put` operation is useless, it will put the very array that it retrieved before. If there wasn’t the mistake that there can be multiple initial values as described above, the `put` operation had no effect.

```
                }

                if (countThreadMap.get(batchIterationTime)[0].get() == 32) {
```

Again, the use of a `ConcurrentMap` doesn’t turn the multi-threaded code into sequential code. While it is clear that the only last thread will update the atomic integer to `32` (when the initial race condition doesn’t materialize), it is not guaranteed that all other threads have already passed this `if` statement. Therefore more than one, up to all threads can still be at this point of execution and see the value of `32`. Or…

```
                    System.out.println("done");
                    countThreadMap.remove(batchIterationTime);
```

One of the threads which have seen the `32` value might execute this `remove` operation. At this point, there might be still threads not having executed the above `if` statement, now not seeing the value `32` but producing a `NullPointerException` as the array supposed to contain the `AtomicInteger` is not in the map anymore. This is what happens, occasionally…

Answer (score 0):

After creating your 10 jobs, your `main` thread is still running - it doesn't wait for your jobs to complete before it calls `report` on the `test`. You try to overcome this with the `while` loop, but `tPoolExecutor.getActiveCount()` is potentially coming out as `0` before the `workerThread` is executed, and then the `countThreadMap.size()` is happening after the threads were added to your `HashMap`.

There are a number of ways to fix this - but I will let another answer-er do that because I have to leave at the moment.

Comment: it makes sense. what about the second issue ?